# Codeigniter - filtering json data by user request

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, firebird

So, I have table ($data) with JSON records getting by select query.

for example:

```
"data": {
        "id": "1",
        "technology_name": "First",
        "technology_info": "Something about first rec",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "technology_name": "Second",
        "technology_info": "Something about second rec",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null  
    }
}
    ...
```

Now I need to create filter by column (technology_name) by user request with 'like', something like

```
select * from "data" where technology_name = '%css%';
```

It is possible to do this with CodeIgniter/PHP code and JSON file, or is better way to do that? Can you give me some advice how to figure it out?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't store JSON data in a relational database. It will be slow and difficult to search and sort. Either use tables and relationships as an SQL database intended, or switch to a NoSQL database like MongoDB, where you can work with JSON-like data directly.

Comment: The problem is that i need to do this with json type.

Comment: @MrCode A lot of database systems have first-class support for JSON, including indexing and such. Unfortunately, Firebird is not one of them.

Comment: It is more than mere support for extra languages (XML, JSON, XML/Binary, EBML, YAML, .... what's next?), there would be a need for a custom program to transform from custom JSON structure into a custom DSQL `select... where` clause. Either doing it in PSQL **Stored Procedure** and `execute statement` or to devise some yet another limited-goal transformaiton language, like the CSS or XSLT but for JSON.  Frankly, it seems that RDBMS here is abused by forcing there functionality normally belonging to app-server layer. Why not just use any HTTP/REST framework?

Comment: Exactly how do you store this JSON in your Firebird database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think that I misspelled my problem. I not store this data as JSON in my db. I get  data by SELECT's and get response  as JSON representation. In this moment I create method that get request from the user, check if my select with where == true and return results.

Comment: @Arioch'The So I decided to modify my script and now I get data by user requests as JSON representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I misspelled my problem.
I was able to find the correct solution.

So, I modified my script that return response as JSON representation with some instructions that SELECT data with WHERE by getting user request params.